# python run code that is in a function once

Tags: python, scope

I am trying to make a variable in Python go up by one continuously, but inside a function. What I am using is something like this:

```
def func1():
   def set1():
      x=5
      y=10
   ##lots of code
   x+=1
   y+=1

def func2():
   while True:
      func1()
set1()
func2()
```

I'm wondering if there is a much better way to do this?

Comment: none of your variables go down by one at all - x and y go up by one each time func1 is called, but in your code they are local to func1 only, and therefore the increase would not be permanent - unless you then do something with those values.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do - please focus your question on what you're trying to achieve, not on how you're doing it.

Comment: Also - have you actually run the code you suggested - I can't see it would even run. for a start the function `set1` is only available inside `func1` and cannot be called separately.

Comment: Plus one for the interesting question, and welcome to Stackoverflow. If I've answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. If it's unclear, I'll be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of code review and recommendations:

```
def func1():
   def set1():
      x=5
      y=10
   ##lots of code
   x+=1
   y+=1

def func2():
   while True:
      func1()

set1() # This won't work because set1 is in the local scope of func1
       # and hidden from the global scope
func2()
```

Looks like you want the function to count each time it is called. May I suggest something like this?:

```
x=5
y=10

def func1():
    global x, y
    x+=1
    y+=1
    print x, y

def func2():
    while True:
        func1()

func2()
```

Better than using a global variable, stick them in a mutable object in a nested scope:

```
Counts = dict(x=5, y=10)

def func1():
    Counts['x'] += 1
    Counts['y'] += 1
    print Counts['x'], Counts['y']

def func2():
    while True:
        func1()

func2()
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to do this is to put the definition of x and y into function 2, and have them be inputs and outputs of function 1.

```
def func1(x, y):
    ##lots of code
    x+=1
    y+=1
    return x, y

def func2():
    x = 5
    y = 10
    while True:
        x, y = func1(x, y)
```

Other alternatives include defining x and y globally and using `global x`, `global y` or using mutable default arguments to make the function retain state, but generally better to not resort to these options if you don't have to.

Comment: much better than using global

Answer (score 1):

```
x = None
y = None

def set1():
    global x, y
    x=5
    y=10

def func1():
    global x, y
    x+=1
    y+=1

def func2():
    while True:
        func1()
set1()
func2()
```

Comment: You mean something like this? You should never use an infinite loop like that.

Comment: You should probably never use global variables like this either!

Comment: You should never use local functions for code this simple.

Answer (score 0):

** just saw the edit on going up instead of down - modified code to suit**

It's hard to tell from your question what your actual use case is but I think a Python generator may be the right solution for you.

```
def generator(x, y):
    yield x,y
    x += 1
    y += 1
```

Then to use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_gen = generator(10,5)

    for x,y in my_gen:
        print x,y
        if x+y > 666:
            break
```

This may be a slightly advanced for someone new to Python. You can read up on generators here: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `set1` function doesn't seem to do much at all, so you could take it away.

If you want to keep count of the number of calls or keep state between calls, the best, more readable way is to keep this inside an object:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._call_count = 0
        self.x = 5

    def func1(self):
        self._call_count += 1
        self.x =  ... Whatever

def func2():
    state = State()
    while True:
        state.func1()
```